# Cannot set Property "Something" of undefined. Trouble with JavaScript "strict mode"!

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble with JavaScript "strict mode". I was coding my library constructor but when I enable strict mode at the beginning of my library like so, `"use strict";` I get this error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'e' of undefined`. The following is my constructor code :-

```
(function(window, document, undefined){
"use strict";

function Ram(CSSselector) { //The main Constructor of the Library
    if (this === window) { return new Ram(CSSselector); }

    if ((CSSselector !== undefined) && (typeof CSSselector === "string")) {
        this.e = catchEl(CSSselector);
    } else {
        this.e = CSSselector;
    }
    this.cssSel = CSSselector;
}

}(this, this.document));
```

**Thanks to @Dave**, I was able to fix my issue in the following way:-

```
function Ram(CSSselector) { //The main Constructor of the Library
    if (this === window) { return new Ram(CSSselector); }

    //This code helps to call the constructor without the new keyword!
    //Thanks to Dave for help!
    if (this instanceof Ram) {
        this.e = ((CSSselector !== undef) && (typeof CSSselector === "string")) ? catchEl(CSSselector) : CSSselector;
        this.cssSel = CSSselector;
    } else {
        return new Ram(CSSselector);
    }
}
```

Comment: In non-strict mode, `this` outside a method refers to the `window` object. Strict mode removes this behaviour. Since you're calling the function with `this` (being the global `this`) as an argument, you get the error.

Comment: So, how should I set those properties without messing up with rest of the library?

Comment: Well for a start you need to change the final line to use `window` instead of `this`. Also your `Ram` function needs to be called via the `new` keyword (calling it as a normal function won't create a `this` object for it to work on). Finally you should look at how closures are written, because your code doesn't quite follow the usual pattern.

Comment: (you're not showing how you call the `Ram` function, but from the error I assume you're calling it as a normal function)

Comment: This closure pattern is recommended by Crockford in his book The Good Parts. What do you mean by change the final line? Do you mean to change (this, this.document) to (window, window.document) ? And yes I'm using my constructor as a function.

Comment: 1: Closures are usually written `(function(){})()` not `(function(){}())`. 2: Yes, I do mean that line. And 3: Yes, if you're calling it as a normal function you will get this error. That's not how JavaScript works (in non-strict mode your code works, but only in a broken way; it will be setting up the object inside the `window` object instead of whatever object you actually intended to set it up in). Here's an overview of objects from Mozilla, I recommend you read this section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_Objects

Comment: Thanks @Dave! I fixed my issue! I updated my answer and showed how I fixed my constructor.

Comment: @Dave: Those are not closures, those are IIFE and it does not matter where you put the parenthesis. I for example *always* use the second way because that's how JSLint preferred it (although I use JSHint now).

Comment: @akash4eva: You can (and probably should) answer your own question instead of editing the question. You might have to wait a bit though. You can even remove the first line (`if (this === window) ...`) from the function.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yes, Crockford calls them dog balls - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGArABpLy0k.

Comment: @Dave how does `(function(){})()` is related to closure ? every function in JS creates a colusre. the main thing is for how long (after the end of the function) the inner function has access to the outer function and its variable. I dont see any usage here for this.

Comment: @various it's only a style choice. I've always used JSHint so I guess that's where I get my style from, but it makes more sense to me than wrapping the whole thing in brackets. Anyway to the OP: this function still has design problems because that function is intended to work as both a function and a constructor. Just change the way you call it to `new Ram(x)` instead of `Ram(x)` (and remove the `this===window` check) and you'll have actual, valid JavaScript.